# New main menu item doesn't work

Tags: 7, routes

After adding new main menu item I received info that it is created, but it is not. I've check watchdog for some error - none. I've cleared caches. None. I've checked db menu_links - new items are there but magically doesn't shows up. Any ideas? Caches cleared.

Drupal 7.37; PHP 5.3.28;

Comment: Clear caches and try again...

Comment: Caches cleared, I know about it. Still nothing.

Comment: Tried both with default theme. Very strange to me.